# Linking paths to libraries on Rust

Tags: rust, path, subdirectory

Given the structure

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── readme.txt
├── src
│   ├── config.rs
│   ├── libraries
│   │   ├──> cryptography::primitives::cipher::symmetric::aes::aes_agent as 
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── header.rs
```

In main.rs:

```
use libraries::cryptography::primitives::cipher::symmetric::aes::aes_agent as aes_cipher;

mod libraries {
    pub mod cryptography {
      pub mod primitives {
        pub mod cipher {
          pub mod symmetric {
            pub mod aes {
                pub mod aes_agent;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

mod header;


fn main() {
    let _ = &aes_cipher::print_me();

    println!("Hello, world in main!");
}
```

however, it does not work in header.rs, giving the error:

```
Compiling lab_00 v0.1.0 (/home/runner/HelloRust)
error[E0583]: file not found for module aes_agent
 --> src/header.rs:9:17
  |
9 |                 pub mod aes_agent;
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
```

The lib code is in libraries/cryptography/primitives/cipher/symmetric/aes/aes_agent. It can be called from main.rs. However, it can't be done in header.rs.

Is there a better means to link the path other than the chunk as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have good reasons for having such a deeply nested singular `.rs` file.

You should only have one `mod <name>;` declaration per `<name>.rs` file you want to use, so if you have `mod aes_agent;` in your `main.rs`, then there should *not* be a `mod aes_agent;` in your `headers.rs` because its already *declared* in `main.rs`. Since its already declared, you simply `use` it:

```
// headers.rs
use crate::libraries::cryptography::primitives::cipher::symmetric::aes::aes_agent;
//  ^^^^^^^ searching for modules starting from the crate root, which is `main.rs`
```

---

Additionally, this is probably a good use of the `#[path]` attribute. With it you can declare a module by file path directly rather than constructing a module hierarchy to reflect the file hierarchy. In general I heavily advise against using this attribute, but this case may warrant it. It would look like this:

```
// main.rs
#[path = "libraries/cryptography/primitives/cipher/symmetric/aes/aes_agent.rs"]
mod aes_agent;
```

The rule above for one `mod` still apply, but this would make your `use` from `headers.rs` much simpler as well: `use crate::aes_agent;`.

Comment: I can't seem to abstract the chunk:
```
mod libraries {
    pub mod cryptography {
      pub mod primitives {
        pub mod cipher {
          pub mod symmetric {
            pub mod aes {
                pub mod aes_agent;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```
away to header.rs

Is there a way to do so?

The reason for the tree is to create categorized cryptographic mechanisms instead of a mess in 1 single folder.

Comment: @MoirisaDikaiosýni You don't put the `mod libraries { ... }` part in `header.rs`, you *only* put it in `main.rs`. Or do you mean you want to put it there *instead* of in `main.rs` ?

Comment: ```
#[path = "libraries/cryptography/primitives/cipher/symmetric/aes/aes_agent.rs"]
mod aes_agent;

:
    //let _ = &aes_cipher::print_me();
    let _ = &aes_agent::print_me();

```

How may I still do
...  aes_cipher as aes_agent?

Comment: @MoirisaDikaiosýni `use aes_agent as aes_cipher;` or if using `#[path]` the module name doesn't need to match the file name, so you could do `#[path = ...] mod aes_cipher;` if you want.